# Issues setting up mail server: relay access denied and mail loops back to myself

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a Debian server with postfix configured with sasl and tls, and dovecot as a mail server.  I'm having two separate problems sending mail to my account on the server.

First, when I send mail from my gmail account, I get

```
Jan  4 23:35:50 avalon postfix/smtpd[2599]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-pb0-f43.google.com[209.85.160.43]: 554 5.7.1 <a@b.com>: Relay access denied; from=<a@gmail.com> to=<a@b.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-pb0-f43.google.com>
```

Doing some research, it seems like the problem is the following two lines

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

I'm a newbie, but from what I've garnered, postfix is serving as a relay server relaying mail from another MTA to dovecot, and only `mynetworks` are allowed to send relay requests.  Is this correct?  If so, how would I fix this?  I would like anyone to be able to send email to this server, but would also like to prevent abuse (e.g., spam).

The second problem is when I try to send email to myself, I get

```
Jan  4 23:53:22 avalon postfix/smtp[2679]: 227D638C7857: to=<a@b.com>, relay=none, delay=0.32, delays=0.09/0/0.23/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for b.com loops back to myself)
```

What exactly is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it figured out.  Adding `permit_auth_destination` to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and with the right `mydestination` allowed mail sent to the server to not bounce.  However, mail was sent to /var/mail/ instead of dovecot.  My `mailbox_command` was `procmail`, so I made a new file `/etc/procmailrc` with the following, as I have dovecot configured to use Maildir format.

```
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir/"
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
```

This second half seems to have fixed the "mail loops back to myself" problems, presumably because `procmail` is not trying to use the default `sendmail` anymore.